# Why is matching rule rewriting going into the URL with iisnode module

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting, iisnode

I'm on windows 2016 and IIS 10 (versions are not so relevant here, but just to say) and I'm using the module iisnode to get the windows authentication into Node.js.
Everything is working fine but I've wrapped my head around the configuration for hours and I'm not sure how to add a little improvement.

The current situation is that I have a script `hello.js`

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer(); // BTW why this deprecated syntax here? 
// maybe just because I've copied the folder from the old examples delivered in the setup!?

app.get('/toh-api/rest/foo', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from foo! [express sample]');
});

app.get('/toh-api/rest/bar', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.headers['x-iisnode-auth_user'];
    const logonuser = req.headers["x-iisnode-logon_user"];
    var authenticationType = req.headers['x-iisnode-auth_type'];
    console.log('username',username);
    console.log('authenicationType',authenticationType)
    res.send('Hello ' + username + ':' + logonuser + ' from bar! [express sample] ' + authenticationType);
});


app.all('/toh-api/rest/hello.js', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from hello.js! [express sample] ');
});
```

and a web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>


    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="my rool for toh">
          <match url="rest/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/toh-api/hello.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>


    <iisnode 
      loggingEnabled="true"
      logDirectory="F:\Logs\myapp\iisnode" 
      promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE,HTTP_UID,LOGON_USER" />
    
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I open a browser from a client machine pointing to the server URL `http://myserver.mydomain/toh-api/rest/bar`, I'm asked the network credential (correct, indeed I've set the win auth on the IIS site) and eventually I see

```
Hello MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME:MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME from bar! [express sample] Negotiate
```

So far, so good.

I'm only a little confused by the IIS URL REWRITE. In this case I've had to put `"rest"` as `match url`, and I need to include this `/rest/` in the final part of my URL (I've really spent hours and made many trials and errors before having it right, like it is now). Ideally, what I would prefer is getting a URL without that part, so let's say `http://myserver.mydomain/toh-api/bar` (notice that `toh-api` is the alias in IIS application, so it must be there, of course). The changes to node.js server file (`hello.js`) are trivial.

What is instead the update for the URL REWRITE part? `<match url="*" />` seems not correct and not working. But I guess it should be feasible (right?), I imagine it is more or less the url rewriting part for an Angular dist under a subfolder of IIS, as far as i can understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I imagine it is more or less the url rewriting part for an Angular
> dist under a subfolder of IIS, as far as i can understand...

Yes, in fact I've copied the idea from a [tutorial of Angular under IIS subfolder](https://indepth.dev/posts/1239/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis).

Now I have (the IIS alias `/toh-api/` part can be skipped from the `url`)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="my app rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="hello.js" />
  </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Only an asterisk `*` is a pattern error in RegEx (hence the `500 Server Error`), you really want a dot asterisk `.*` - meaning any sequence, including 0 occurrences, of any chars - so a **dot** is **needed** in `url=".*"` (to avoid a `500 Server Error`) and it *does the trick*! Problem solved (with the obvious changes in `hello.js`). Btw, the `stopProcessing="true"` seems not necessary instead.

Another **simpler** option is `patternSyntax="Wildcard"` inside the tag with the rule name. In that case just the asterisk is perfectly fine.

## Verbs PUT and DELETE ##

However, I've notice an obscure bug for verbs PUT and DELETE: they are not IIS URL rewritten and they cause a **404** not found error (maybe it's worth a follow up question).


(put and delete verbs, also [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67166686/11323942))