# URL Rewrite in case of verbs PUT and DELETE with iisnode

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-delete, iisnode, http-put

This is a follow-up question to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67158678/11323942), focused on the fact that I'm getting a 404 error when I try to call a DELETE or a PUT verb for an Node.JS application on IIS configured with **iisnode** and URL Rewrite as follows:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" verb="*" path="app.js" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="my app rule" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
  </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The script app.js is not even called, the url is not rewritten.

Is it a well known bug or what else am I supposed to do?

No issues for GET and PUT verbs instead (and of course I've already implemented a workaround using the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was due to the Request Filtering of IIS (tab HTTP Verbs)

Added there the missing verbs as shown in the screenshot below and problem solved.

[image]

As text, directly inside the `system.webServer` of the `web.config`:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```